# Multiple NET Core web applications each listening in different ports and Kestrel

Tags: web-services, kestrel

I have a Web application based on framework installed in IIS Windows 2012 R2. Let's call it Web1.
Web1 has been performing for years. Avoiding a huge monolithic grow, I have created new developments in different Web Applications based on .NET Core 6, each with own port, each Kestrel based, some are Web applications, other are WebAPI applications( Web2,Web3,...WebN).
From Web1, via links, user invokes Web2,Web3, etc.The whole assemble works in development box,local host,perfectly as console apps and as Windows Services.
In production, Web2,Web3...WebN have their ports open for inbound and outbound rules. however, just one app(windows service),Web3, in port X works. Documentation found is unclear or misleading.
Should I hook Web2...WebN to just one Windows Service?. Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated especially because the whole set of applications are to be migrated to HTTPS server

I tried to make a set of .NET Core application to run each in different ports based on Kestrel.
I expected they work perfectly. The result is that just one application runs properly.